# unity-place-filesearch doesn't seem to work

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Unity PLace Filesearch does not seem to on my computer (Ubuntu 11.10). I have followed these instructions...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pydave/unity-lenses
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-place-filesearch
```

... the repository adds OK but when I sudo apt-get update, I get...
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pydave/unity-lenses/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

And then when I try to install...

```
E: Unable to locate package unity-place-filesearch
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're running ubuntu 11.10 but the PPA you mention only has packages for Ubuntu 11.04.

I think you'll need to wait for the author of this program to update it to provide 11.10 packages.

The page for the FileSearch lens is here:

https://launchpad.net/filesearch-lens